# Как решить проблему с масштабированием на телефоне?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть модалка, которая вызывается по клику на картинку и показывает слайдер из картинок. На телефоне.

Даже не знаю как и где искать решение таких багов. Может хоть кто направит)
На всякий случай - проект на React, в head стоит content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no",

Проблема 1)
В том, что когда двумя пальцами увеличиваешь на телефоне картинку в модалке, то словно все перестраивается. Увеличивается весь контент, и теряется место увеличения
Например, хочу увеличить диван слева:
до увеличения -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после увеличения -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема 2)
Когда уменьшаешь назад, то появляется на мгновения белые пятна/квадраты, как будто картинка заново подгружается (картинка показан другая). Сами картинки +/- 100 кб

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая OS, версия , браузер, версия. Белые пятна - проблема рендеринга в некоторых старых браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

Убрать полностью возможность приближать пальцами контент )? Вот так вот:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: странный ответ ........